# Debugging project generated by Gradle on Eclipse 

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, gradle

I have an issue - the command "gradle eclipse" generates the necessary Eclipse WTP files. I can import the project into Eclipse, but when I deploy to Glassfish it does not copy anything to Glassfish's `eclipseApp` directory.

I verified that the project is a Dynamic Web Facet but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Has anybody ever encountered such issue?

Comment: Are you deploying in Eclipse?  Is Eclipse building the project correctly?

Comment: Comparing the Gradle-generated vs. the Eclipse-generated files would start to give you an idea of what might be missing...

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a very common issue. Typically, when you use one builder to generate project files for you, or even a custom plug-in to detect change events, rebuild your app with a custom script and hot-deploy it to your app server.

The Dynamic Web Facet is one thing, but when gradle generates your project file, it does not know what app server you will be using. 
Go into Project Properties -> Facets -> Dynamic Web -> Runtimes and then configure your GF instance or link it.

You might have already done it but that's my 2 cents about what's wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work for you, do you still have that problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are using eclipse plugin to do so. Here is what you can do further to ensure gradle cleanEclipse and gradle eclipse continue to play nice with your project.

Watch what natures and build Commands are required in your .project file. Once you are aware of them all, the next thing to do is configure the eclipse task like so

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
eclipse {
    project {
        name = 'eclipse-appname'

        natures << 'org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature'
        buildCommand 'org.eclipse.....Validator'
        buildCommand 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder'
    }
}
```

I have added natures and build commands randomly, replace with the appropriate ones that you see in your .project.